# How can i make the width of a div respond to the width of a div a few parent levels above?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="navrow1">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="">content</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="">content</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="">content</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="">content</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="">content</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but am I able to say have a container div, with a few levels of divs nested and then somehow make the width of the most nested div react % wise to the main div?

For example with the above HTML, is there a way I could say make the "dropdown-content" class have, for example, 50% of the width of the main "navrow1" div?

How could one go about doing that?

More directly to the point its a nav bar with dropdown menus for each item, I would like to have the "dropdown-content" (the box that appears when nav item selected) to take up 50% of the entire navbar1. any width I set just goes to the parent class it currently has and needs.

also sorry if there's anything wrong with the way this is layed out I am new to this so please just tell me anything I do wrong so I can correct it.

Comment: Just apply it what you have said. Check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/pc6ync5r/

Comment: I got the same results as @SureshPonnukalai, I'm not sure what the problem is? Could you give us the CSS that you've tried? it may be more effective.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Fdhu7Y9 heres a picture of what I mean, I didn't mention the list is inline, when I nav item is hovered and the drop down list appears, I want each of their width to be 50% of the whole nav bar div

Comment: picture less helpful than your css.

Answer (score 0):

idk why I didn't think of it earlier but I just set the width using the vw unit.